# Serialize List of Python Objects to JSON

Tags: python, json, dictionary, serialization, defaultdict

I've searched SO's posts but couldn't figure out solution to my problem. I've seen bunch of SO posts which explains how to serialize python objects haven't found anything which explains how to serialize dictionary of list of python objects.

Here's the problem statement and sample use-case:

```
import json  
import collections    
from collections import defaultdict     

class A:
    def __init__(self, a1_list=[], a2_str=None):
        self.a1_list  = []
        self.a2_str = a2_str

class B:
     def __init__(self, list_of_A_objects=[], b2_str=None):
        self.list_of_A_objects = list_of_A_objects
        self.b2_str = b2_str

if __name__ == "__main__":
     a1 = A([1, 2, 3], '123')
     a2 = A([4, 5, 6], '456')
     b1 = B([a1, a2], '123-456')

     a3 = A([11, 22, 33], '112233')
     a4 = A([44, 55, 66], '445566')
     b2 = B([a3, a4], '112233-445566')

     dict_b = defaultdict(list)
     dict_b['b'].append(b1)
     dict_b['b'].append(b2)
     json.dumps(dict_b)
```

Error is thrown at the last line `json.dumps(dict_b)` saying

> TypeError: Object of type 'B' is not JSON serializable

**EDIT:**

> I've tried pickle as @coldspeed has suggested in the comments, but I'd
>   like to view the dumped JSON with a text editor. If I use pickle, I
>   can't view it since it is dumped in binary format.

Am I doing anything incorrectly?

Comment: `json` does not support python objects, try pickle?

Comment: @coldspeed: Thanks for the suggestion. Do you have any sample example?

Comment: See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968884/python-serialization-why-pickle

Comment: @coldspeed: Thanks. Apparently, some SO posts such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768895/how-to-make-a-class-json-serializable and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252010/serializing-class-instance-to-json?rq=1 shows how to use `json` to serialize python objects to JSON string.

Comment: also you can use yaml https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52235173/how-to-change-string-object-location-to-an-object/52235347#52235347

Comment: I should have been more specific - it is not supported out-of-box. You need to define custom encoders and decoders, which you haven't done yet.

Comment: @coldspeed: Actually, with pickle dumping in binary format, I can't read the dumped JSON using any text editor. I would like to view the dumped json. Is there a way to achieve it using JSONEncoder?

Comment: I'm not familiar with JSONEncoder, but I just now remembered having written an answer once to do something similar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45834618/4909087

Answer (score 2):

You could define a method to dump you classe to json with `json.dumps`.

```
import json  
from collections import defaultdict

class A:
    def __init__(self, items=[], string=None):
        self.items = items
        self.string = string

    def toJSON(self):
        return json.dumps(self, default=lambda obj: obj.__dict__)#, sort_keys=True, indent=4)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a1 = A([1, 2, 3], '123')
    a2 = A([4, 5, 6], '456')
    b1 = A([a1, a2], '123-456')
    print(b1.toJSON())
    # Result: {"items": [{"items": [1, 2, 3], "string": "123"}, {"items": [4, 5, 6], "string": "456"}], "string": "123-456"}

    a3 = A([11, 22, 33], '112233')
    a4 = A([44, 55, 66], '445566')
    b2 = A([a3, a4], '112233-445566')

    dict_b = defaultdict(list)
    dict_b['b'].append(b1.toJSON())
    dict_b['b'].append(b2.toJSON())
    print(json.dumps(dict_b))
```

**Disadvantages** 
You always will have a serialized version of your class. To avoid this side effect you can set a new method to turn back it to a dict with `loads`

```
def to_dict(self):
    return json.loads(self.toJSON())
```

And at defaultdict append `object.to_dict`

```
dict_b = defaultdict(list)
dict_b['b'].append(b1.to_dict())
dict_b['b'].append(b2.to_dict())
print(json.dumps(dict_b))
```